# How To Check empty Lines?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, ifstream

my input.txt file:

```
4

4

5 0 1 2
1 4 0 0
1 1 5 4
0 6 3 2

0 4 1 2
1 7 5 0
2 3 5 6
0 6 2 2

1:0 4 2 0
```

my program for now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream File("input.txt");
string line;
string num;
string array[50];
string comma;
int i=0;
    while (getline(File,line)) {

        comma="";
        istringstream s(line);

        if (line.empty()){

            comma=",";
            s >> num ;
            array[i] =  comma;
        }

        else {
            s >> num ;
            array[i] =  num;
        }
        i++;

    }        
return 0;
}
```

well, my program is not giving me what I want! when I print the array[i] its giving me only the numbers in the first Column! like this :

```
4
,
4
,
5
3
1
7
,
0
1
2
6
,
1:0
```

what i want to do is to put a comma where ever there is an empty line , so I can **distinguish between these numbers** and store them inside an **intger** array to do **mathematical operations between them**.

to explain my input.txt file:

> numbers and matrix size inside input file can be changed by me.

```
4 <= #number of items 

4 <= #types of items

5 0 1 2 <= matrix #1
1 4 0 0
1 1 5 4
0 6 3 2

0 4 1 2 <= matrix #2
1 7 5 0
2 3 5 6
0 6 2 2

1:0 4 2 0 <= Available numbers for item #1
```

and I want to :

1. store number of items inside a variable.
2. store types of items inside a variable.
3. store **matrix #1** and **matrix #2** inside a an **2 arrays** and do **Subtraction** between **matrix #1 and matrix #2.**

Can this be done ? or is there any easier method to distinguish between these numbers and store them inside variables and an inter array ?

Comment: Could your input lines be terminated in `\r\n` (ie. Windows line endings)?

Comment: You say it's not giving you what you want, but you don't say what it **is** giving you.  I suspect the the problem is that you never clear out `comma`, so once it's set, you end up putting a comma after all later lines (empty or not). If that's your problem, add an `else { comma = "" }` to your one `if` statement.  If not, then you'll need to add details to the question.

Comment: @clcto  sorry for not clearing my problem very well, I have edited my post hoping its more clear to you now ?

Comment: Thanks for the additional information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simple.

You read a line of data with

```
while (getline(File,line)) {
```

But then you only process one element from that line:

```
    if (line.empty()) {
        ...
        s >> num ;
        ...
    }
    else {
        s >> num ;
    }
```

You simply need to put that `if ... else` statement into some kind of loop.

Additionally, I don't understand the first branch of that `if` statement:  if `line` is empty, there shouldn't be anything in `s` to read from.

So, slightly edited, this should be closer to what you're looking for (I haven't tried this to see if it actually works):

```
    ...
    while (getline(File,line)) {
        if (line.empty()) {
            array[i] = ","
            ++i;
            continue;
        }
        istringstream s(line);

        while(s >> num) {
            array[i] =  num;
            ++i;
        }
    }        
    return 0;
}
```